# iOS app crashes when run under iOS 8.1 debugger, but not on device or simulator outside debugger

Tags: debugging, uitextfield, xcode6.1, ios8.1

**RESOLVED:** I have an iPad app (XCode 6.1, iOS 8.1.1, objective-c, ARC and Storyboards).  When I run the app using the debugger, the app crashes.  This *only* happens with the 'en' simulator; **all** of the other eight language simulators work fine!

If I run the app *outside* of the 8.1 debugger, either on the device or the simulator, it runs fine.

I have restarted OSX (Yosemite), reset the simulator device, restarted XCode and nothing changes.  I have looked at all occurrances of 'objectAtIndex' and they all refer to NSArrays or NSMutableArrays.  I had a similar problem several weeks ago, removed some code that wasn't being used and the problem appeared to go away.  Well, it's back again; I have spent 3 days trying everything I know of to fix it.

Comment: you don't even mentioned wich language so I assume some kind of C. That usually happens because of invalid memory access that would result in undefined behaviour if not catched in debug mode or some assertion that is disabled in release mode.

Comment: I don't know so I can't answer :D

Comment: Can you update the stack trace to show more frames?  Sometimes there are hints in what it's doing even if it's not directly your code.

Comment: Do you have any object that handles keyboard notifications or any custom input class?  Failing that, I'd try running with a scheme that had zombies enabled to see what array got replaced by a string. ([NSCFString objectAtIndex:])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**  I had to modify the simulator settings for 'en' to look like this:

[image]

It works fine now!  Keeping my fingers crossed!